# OData with WCF REST

Tags: wcf, rest, odata, wcf-data-services, wcf-rest

I have a WCF REST Service that I have implemented all single result endpoints.  Now I need to implement endpoints that return collections.  I realize there is the WCF DataServices that will allow me to return ATOM, but that requires a new service definition.  Is there any way to have my existing REST endpoints that return collections expose that data as OData without creating a whole new service?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to write OData provided you aren't looking to use any OData V3 features I would suggest the [OData Library](http://odata.codeplex.com/releases/view/60787). Its an open source OData serialization library for .Net. This doesn't do any fancy service stuff it exists solely for writing. Please note though that this is a pre-release.